# text_parser in pyhton with split but there is have problem with output

Tags: python, class, split

```
    def parse_rows(self):
        rows = self.string.split("\n")
        cleaned_rows = [list(map(str.strip, row.split(self.delimiter))) for row in rows if row.strip()]
        return cleaned_rows

    def parse_columns(self):
        cols = [list(col) for col in zip(*self.rows)]
        return cols

 S = """a , b  , c,  d
             e,   f, g,h
              j,k,l,m"""
    tp = text_parser( S, "," )
    rows = tp.parse_rows()
    print( rows )
```

should print out(like column , top to down) the following:

```
          [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
           ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
           ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm']]
```

but its : `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm']]`

again same with parse_columns

i tried this

```
For row in cleaned_rows:
 Print(row) but its going None when whe Try to print(row) i mean tp = text_parser( S, "," )
    rows = tp.parse_rows() : answer 
    print( rows ) output: None
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and describe further how you want the output to be? What should be the output for string `aaa, a, b\nx, cccccc`?

Comment: i did it, i want that when we print(row) it should output column by column the answer  but its responds None